# How to continue the previous action after login

Tags: php, session, redirect

I want to redirect the user to the application form of the job he is applying to after successful login.
I have a page on which the job description is showed and I want to check and redirect the user if he is not authenticated to the login/registration page and then continue back with the applying process.
how should I achieve this?

Comment: what did you try in order to resolve this yourself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+login+previous+page

Comment: I thought of storing the last action, in this case, the id of the job he is applying too and the action i.e apply in a session variable and redirect to it after successful session creation.

Comment: Just look at how stackoverflow does it if you try to ask a question without being logged in: https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2fask - See the returnurl param?

Comment: @MikeB I guess it passes the last action as a parameter(returnurl) in the URL and redirects back after to the url successful creation of a session ??